# How to send emails from within R using a loop

Tags: r, email, loops

The R code below sends email to the recipients whose email addresses are read from a text file named `email`. Since Gmail does not allow to send more than 100 in one go, I want to use a loop which will send email to the first 100 and then 101-200, and then 201-300 and so on. Can any please help me with that?

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "xyz@gmail.com"
recipients <- scan("email.txt", encoding="UTF-8",character(0))
send.mail(from = sender,
to = recipients,
subject="Subject of the Mail",
body = "Body of the Mail",
smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
    user.name="convert2latex@gmail.com", passwd="Mypassword", ssl=TRUE),
    authenticate = TRUE, send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `for` loop (look at `?"for"`)? It's a bit hard for us to understand what exactly you are unclear about. In addition, Gmail may monitor your access, and if you start spam-bombing them, they may lock you out, so you may want to wait for a couple of seconds between iterations.

Comment: I am not unclear about anything. I know what I want to do, but don't know how. I am not very good at loops. I tried to use for and repeat loops together, but could get anything valuable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Gmail Sending Limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en), you can send to up to 99 addresses with one email. Maybe you want to put those into the BCC field? Here is a test example for Gmail (remember to [allow unsecure apps first](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureap) and to specify `sender`, `user.name` and `passwd`):

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "...@gmail.com" # gmail user
# create 5 test addresses from `sender`
testEmails <- paste(sapply(1:5, function(x) sub("(.*)(@.*)", paste0("\\1+test", x, "\\2"), sender)), collapse = "\n") 
cat(testEmails) # print the addresses 
recipients <- scan(file = textConnection(testEmails), encoding="UTF-8",character(0))

## Create a list of vectors of emails with the max size adrPerBatch each
getRecipientBatches <- function(emails, adrPerBatch = 98) {
  cuts <- seq(from = 1, to = length(emails), by = adrPerBatch)
  recipientBatches <- lapply(cuts, function(x) c(na.omit(emails[x:(x+adrPerBatch-1)])))
  return(recipientBatches)
}

## send the 3 test batches à 2/1 address(es)
res <- lapply(getRecipientBatches(recipients, adrPerBatch = 2), function(recipients) {
  send.mail(from =  sender,
            to = sender,
            bcc = recipients,
            subject="Subject of the Mail",
            body = "Body of the Mail",
            smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
                        port = 465, 
                        user.name = "...", 
                        passwd = "...", 
                        ssl = TRUE),
            authenticate = TRUE, 
            send = TRUE)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **untested**, but should give you a jump board for your own explorations. Conceptually this is like a `for` loop, but the `FUN` is applied to `recipients` for each factor in `INDEX`. I'm using `tapply`, which cuts `recipients` according to `INDEX` (feel free to calculate your own). You can insert `Sys.sleep` to prevent the "loop" to send too fast.
If you insert `browser()` as the first line of the function (and run it), you'll be placed inside the function and you can further explore what it's doing.

```
tapply(X = recipients, INDEX = as.integer(cumsum(rep(1, 252))/100), FUN = function(x, recipients, sender) {
  send.mail(from = sender,
            to = recipients,
            subject="Subject of the Mail",
            body = "Body of the Mail",
            smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                        user.name="convert2latex@gmail.com", passwd="Mypassword", ssl=TRUE),
            authenticate = TRUE, send = TRUE)
}, recipients = recipients, sender = sender)
```